# Count Bits from unsigned integer

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to write a function that takes an (unsigned) integer as input, and returns the number of bits that are equal to one in the binary representation of that number.

Example: The binary representation of 1234 is 10011010010, so the function should return 5 in this case.

Here is my answer:

```
var newArr;
var count = 0;
function countBits(num){
    newArr = num.toString(2).split('').map(function(el){
        if(el == '1')
            count++
    });;
    return count;  
}
```

In my program when I call countBits(7) it returns //3 but when I submit my response it says it is returning //4. Can someone see what I am missing in my response based on question?

Comment: See what happens when you call your function twice on the same number.

Comment: It's possible that their test harness is calling `countBits` multiple times. You never reset the `count` to `0`, so it sums up the total it has counted across all calls. `var count = 0;` should be inside your function instead of before it, and you don't even need the `newArr` variable. You could use `forEach` or `reduce` instead of map. There is no point on using `map` if you don't return a value in the callback function it accepts. `forEach` makes much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are declaring the variables outside of the function, so when the function is called multiple times they'll keep their values and just increase the count.

Btw, you also shouldn't use `map` if you don't want to create another array - so better do

```
function countBits(num){
    var newArr = num.toString(2).split('').map(Number);
    var count = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<newArr.length; i++)
        count += newArr[i];
    }
    return count;  
}
```

or

```
function countBits(num){
    return num.toString(2).split('').reduce(function(count, el) {
        return count + (el == "1");
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: Or (length - sumOfArray)

Answer (score 0):

```
function countBits(num){

    // convert num Base10 to Base2
    let base2 = num.toString(2)

    // declare variable for sum of bits 
    let sum = 0

    // for loop to check bits (bit = 1) and ignore Zeros in the String base2 
    for(let i = 0; i <  base2.length; i++){
        if(base2[i] == 1){
            // use Number() to convert string to number
            count += Number(base2[i])
        } 
    }
    return sum ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function countBits(num){

    /* Convert num Base10 to num Base2 
    then find Ones and save them in an array
    length of the array is equal their sum */

    return num.toString(2).match(/1/g).length
}
```